# How did Pepper use the Rescue armor in "Avengers: Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

As Marvel showed in *Iron Man*, Tony was not able to grab control of his suit immediately in the first few attempts.

So how did Pepper Potts, who never wanted him to do all that shooting, blasting, fighting stuff, control the Rescue armor in *Endgame* so well?

Comment: How did Pepper use the Rescue armour? _Very carefully._

Answer (score 22):

### This was probably not her first time using the armor

Pepper is a smart woman.  She would have known that as soon as Tony got involved with the Avengers again, there was a chance that things would go wrong and they would need help ('rescue', if you would).  It's unclear how long it took to develop and build the time travel device, but it was likely several months at least given the complexity of the project.  Plenty of time for Pepper to practice with her suit of armor.

### Tony is constantly redesigning and improving his suit designs - that includes the control interfaces

Tony's original suit (the one built "in a cave, with a box of scraps") was controlled entirely by feedback from user movements.  His next iteration was largely designed the same way, but augmented by integrating J.A.R.V.I.S. into the control systems.

Since then, Tony has spent a ton of time refining the suits' design.  In *Infinity War*, his personal suit is no longer controlled mechanically at all, and is instead linked directly to his brainwaves, giving him the ability to control his suit with the speed of thought, and allowing him to achieve many feats with his nanobot suit that would be impossible to design into a more mundane control system.  It seems unlikely that the suits he makes for other people have the same level of control, but even a small bit of biofeedback could greatly enhance the suit's control.

Pepper's suit undoubtedly has a great deal more stabilization and autonomy than Tony's original suits had, making it much more user-friendly and needing a lot less practice to use effectively.

Comment: *"This suit is, like, ridiculously intuitive"*

Comment: @Valorum, that's a Spiderman quote, right?

Comment: Yes, from Infinity War, said by Spider-Man

Comment: Don't forget prior to the time heist, Morgan is already playing with the Rescue helmet. So the armor is made. Now, given the events of the snap did Pepper get some practice in? My opinion is that now being a mother Pepper might take some extra steps to defend the family.

Comment: Yes, exactly. When Tony first flew in the suits, it was the first time it had ever been done by anyone and the technology was garage-design level. The first time I ever stepped into a light airplane, I was able to fly it much better than the Wright brothers were able to fly theirs when they first started flying, too. - haha - Lots of design improvements and improvement of knowledge of how to control an airplane took place between those events.

Comment: It also wasn't Pepper's first time in the armor.  She might not have been doing anything when Tony used it to save her during the attack on their house, but she was definitely in control when she shot off Killian's head at the end.